# Page Background for Certain Pages Only

Tags: backgrounds, page, border, calc, tikz-calc

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
color=black,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
contents={\tikz\draw[line width=1pt,rounded corners,black]
  ( $ (current page.south east) + (-4,6) $ ) rectangle ( $ (current page.north west) + (2,2) $ );}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage

\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

[image]

[image]

QUESTION: How may I remove the page background for the first page (i.e., first four paragraphs)---and keeping the page backgrounds in tact for the last two pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two definitions in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\def\back{\backgroundsetup{
color=black,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
contents={\tikz\draw[line width=1pt,rounded corners,black]
  ( $ (current page.south east) + (-4,6) $ ) rectangle ( $ (current page.north west) + (2,2) $ );}
}}


\def\noback{\backgroundsetup{contents={}}}


\begin{document}
\noback{\lipsum[1-4]}

\newpage

\back{\lipsum[1-8]}
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

[image]

[image]